# What exactly Looper and Handler used for?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm learning about `Looper` `Handler` and I found that mostly this is being used for working with UI thread. Then I'm little confused when we need child class of Handler and use of `handleMessage` method.

Example we can work with UI thread by just simple example.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    // update UI here
  }
});
```

We can easily communicate with UI thread by just short code. Here handler will automatically will be connected with MainLooper.

Then when wee need to use child class of Handler and working with `handleMessage(Message msg)` method.

Answer (score 0):

> Looper is a class used to run a message loop for a thread. Threads by
> default do not have a message loop associated with them; to create
> one, call prepare() in the thread that is to run the loop, and then
> loop() to have it process messages until the loop is stopped.

Read more about Looper class [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html).

> There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and
> runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to
> enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

Read more about Handler class [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: I already read the docs but still didn't understand. I asked when to need child class of handler? and need override `handleMessage(Message m);`